# What are the HighPoint, SoftRAID macOS software extensions?

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extensions, plugins, system-information

While cleaning some software off my computer, I noticed the following extensions listed in System Information → Software → Extensions. For context, I am running an M2 Max MacBook Pro with MacOS Ventura 13.4.

I did not ever install applications by "HighPoint Technologies" or "Other World Computing," and I certainly never approved the activation of system software by either of these developers.

**Can someone tell me what these pieces of software are, whether they should be on my Mac, and—if not—how I can get rid of them?**

> **HighPointIOP:**
>
> Version:    4.4.5
> Last Modified:  2023-05-12, 18:29
> Bundle ID:  com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointIOP
> Notarized:  Yes
> Loaded: No
> Get Info String:    Version: 4.4.5, Copyright (c) 2020 HighPoint Technologies, Inc.
> Obtained from:  Identified Developer
> Kind:   Intel
> Architectures:  x86_64
> 64-Bit (Intel): Yes
> Location:   /Library/Extensions/HighPointIOP.kext
> Kext Version:   4.4.5
> Loadable:   Yes
> Dependencies:   Incomplete
> Dependency Errors:
> Dependency Resolution Failures:
> Indirect dependencies can't be resolved:    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIParallelFamily, com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily
> Signed by:  Developer ID Application: HighPoint Technologies, Inc (DX6G69M9N2), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
>
> **HighPointRR:**
>
> Version:    4.22.1
> Last Modified:  2023-05-12, 18:29
> Bundle ID:  com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR
> Notarized:  Yes
> Loaded: No
> Get Info String:    Version: 4.22.1, Copyright (c) 2020 HighPoint Technologies, Inc.
> Obtained from:  Identified Developer
> Kind:   Intel
> Architectures:  x86_64
> 64-Bit (Intel): Yes
> Location:   /Library/Extensions/HighPointRR.kext
> Kext Version:   4.22.1
> Loadable:   Yes
> Dependencies:   Incomplete
> Dependency Errors:
> Dependency Resolution Failures:
> Indirect dependencies can't be resolved:    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIParallelFamily, com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily
> Signed by:  Developer ID Application: HighPoint Technologies, Inc (DX6G69M9N2), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
>
> **SoftRAID:**
>
> Version:    6.3.1
> Last Modified:  2023-02-09, 04:39
> Bundle ID:  com.softraid.driver.SoftRAID
> Notarized:  Yes
> Loaded: No
> Get Info String:    SoftRAID version 6.3.1, Copyright © 2002-22 Other World Computing, Inc.  All rights reserved.
> Obtained from:  Identified Developer
> Kind:   Intel
> Architectures:  x86_64
> 64-Bit (Intel): Yes
> Location:   /Library/Extensions/SoftRAID.kext
> Kext Version:   6.3.1
> Loadable:   Yes
> Dependencies:   Incomplete
> Dependency Errors:
> Dependency Resolution Failures:
> Indirect dependencies can't be resolved:    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
> Signed by:  Developer ID Application: Other World Computing (Q9P8K45M5C), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't find softRAID. It's a well known product, and top of the list for a google search. https://softraid.com I have all those extensions (though I'm surprised they are not Universal Binaries, if part of the OS).

Comment: @benwiggy For softRAID, at least I could tell what its purpose was by the name. Do you have the HighPoint extensions on your Mac, though? I can't quite tell what those are based on the names.

Comment: Are you running macOS Ventura 13.4? No need to edit that in if you like the answer provided. If not, make sure you add your specific build and people can validate they have the exact same versions as you...

Comment: I am running Ventura 13.4—I'll add that detail to my question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HighPoint and SoftRAID (OWC) are both OEMs that supply products for macOS and have contracted with Apple to include drivers with the operating system to support products “out of the box.”  This is not unlike what other vendors do with Windows operating system where drivers are included or bundled with the OS.

- Highpoint makes RAID enclosures, NMMe drives, USB, Thunderbolt and other devices.  A [current list of their supported products](https://filedn.com/lG3WBCwKGHT7yNuTsFCwXy0/HighPoint-Download/Document/Support/HighPoint%20Product%20macOS%20Support%20List_2023_04_06.pdf) can be found on their website.  Items marked with a red asterisk are embedded with macOS.

  - HighPointRR likely refers to the “Rocket Raid” line of products
  - HighPointOP likely refers to a software like GUI extensions
- [OWC SoftRAID](https://www.owc.com/solutions/softraid) kext is what allows you to create software defined RAID arrays on macOS.

This is a very common practice, for third party developers and OEMs to include drivers with a shipping OS.  You’ll find that HP will supply drivers for their most popular printers with macOS just like they do with Windows.

**Should you worry about these kexts?**

No.  They aren’t loaded.  The fifth line down from the top of each kext description indicates that it’s not loaded.  The kext is there should you attach one of these supported devices, but as it stands, it’s just there doing nothing and not loaded and running.

Comment: Interestingly, you can't read a SoftRAID array if you don't have a valid licensed copy of the app (which installs kexts anyway), so I don't know what the point of these bundled drivers is.

Comment: I’m thinking legacy SoftRAID arrays or perhaps it’s for use with a different OEM that included SoftRAID with their product.

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 13.3, the SoftRAID driver is installed by the macOS Installer in `/System/Library/Extensions`.  The version for macOS 13.3 and later versions is 7.5.  The version of the SoftRAID driver for macOS 14.0 and later is 7.6.

Older versions of the SoftRAID driver may reside in `/Library/Extensions` but if you are running macOS 13.3 or later, they will be ignored.  These older versions are residual from upgrading from an older version of macOS rather than performing a clean install.

As of macOS 13.3, your SoftRAID volume never requires the SoftRAID application to mount, the driver is always authorized and ready to load and your volume will mount as soon as you connect your SoftRAID formatted disks.  This will be true going forward to future versions of macOS.